Develop and integrate whatsapp into my website
I’m developing a custom crm in react and nodejs.
I need to integrate a box in which the user/operator can message through whatsapp to the customers.
I read that I can’t use the iframe cause there are some several restrictions.
How can I add this feature?
ps: I don’t want to open new tab in the browser and redirect to whatsapp web.

I'm afraid this is not possible due to restrictions by Meta/WhatsApp. The WhatsApp Business API only offers to build a custom interface from the "business-side" but not from side of the customer.

my goal is that the operator can message from the crm and chat from it using whatsapp integrate. the customer can respond normally(by whatsapp web or mobile).  cause the customer can't use the crm

Yes, that is possible. In this case, you need to follow the WhatsApp Self Sign-up with the Twilio Console and then you can use the regular messaging API to integrate this in your CRM
